# How to save firebase in shared_preferences

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I want to save name of Category in my application in shared_preferences that the name come from firebase

that the code of how I get my category

the idea of program that the user only use on category not all of them

in the first the user will chose the category I have to save the Category in the app that come from firebase

```
 final CollectionReference _categoryCollectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Country');

Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> getCategory() async {
    var value = await _categoryCollectionRef.get();
    return value.docs;
  }

getCategory() async {
    _loading.value = true;
    await HomeService().getCategory().then((value) => {
          for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
            {
              _categoryModel.add(CategoryModel.fromJson(
                  value[i].data() as Map<String, dynamic>)),
              _loading.value = false,
            },
          update(),
        });
  }
```

that the button I call it my function

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                Get.off(
                  ControlView(),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), color: primary),
                height: 50,
                child: CustomText(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  text: controller.categoryModel[index].name,
                ),
              ),
            );
```

Comment: you mean save in shared_preferences?

Comment: yup i just want save the name of category

Comment: which func is your main function for getting category? you have two getCategory?

Comment: get getCategory is main function

Comment: you have a list of category, do want to save the list or just on category?

Comment: I just want save one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and do like this:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().reload();
prefs.setString('uniquekey', 'name of Category');
```

in your case:

```
    onTap: () async {
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().reload();
        prefs.setString('categoryName', controller.categoryModel[index].name);

        Get.off(
          ControlView(),
        );
    },
```

and read it like this:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().reload();
String result = prefs.get('categoryName');
if(result != null){
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: tell me the condition of that category you wnat to save, so I can updated my answer.

Comment: I just want to save the name of category thay are a list of category but i want when the user click on the category the name save on the shared_performance

Comment: when user click on button which function call? could you add that code too?

Comment: for sure i added on the code

Comment: await sharedp?.setString(
                    NAME_OF_CONTRY, controller.categoryModel[index].name);
                print(sharedp?.getString(NAME_OF_CONTRY));  I add this to my code but it allwas return null

Comment: are you calling sharedp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().reload(); every time you want to use sharedp?

Comment: there is an anthoer issue i use Get x that make the data deleted so it delete the data i saved

Comment: why do you want save the category that you are delete with Getx?

Comment: it is deleted automatically